# Mapping methods in Jersey framework

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

Is it possible to map methods to methods calls to URL path both with ID and with parameters? For instance:
**http://localhost/ws/updateUser/32332?name=John?psw=123**

public void updateUser(Sting name, String psw){..}

It seems that current @PathParam annotation supports only parameters in path, like:
**http://localhost/ws/updateUser/32332/John/123**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `@QueryParam` to capture `name` and `psw` parameters:-

```
public void updateUser(@QueryParam Sting name, @QueryParam String psw) {
   ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine @QueryParam and @PathParam in one method:

```
@GET
@Path("/user/{userId}")
public ShortLists getShortListsOfUser(@PathParam("userId") String userId,
                                    @QueryParam("pageNumber") Integer pageNumber,
                                    @QueryParam("pageSize") Integer pageSize,
                                    @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
   /*do something*/
}
```

This method matches http://localhost/api**/user/222?pageNumber=1&pageSize=3**

---

When using a UriBuilder to run this method, mind to use queryParam:

```
URI uri = getBaseUriBuilder().path("/user/user111").queryParam("pageSize", 2)
              .queryParam("pageNumber", 3).build();
```

This doesn't work: *getBaseUriBuilder().path("/user/user111?pageSize=2&pageNumber=3").build();*
(because the question mark is replaced with *%3F* by the builder)